# Linear algebra - determinant of $n\times n$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this question:

> Solve the next determinant:

$D = \begin{vmatrix}
 1&  1& *&  *&  1&  1& \\ 
 1&  1&  *&  *&  1&  2& \\ 
 *&  *&  *&  1&  3&  1& \\ 
 *&  *&  *&  4&  1&  1& \\ 
 *&  *&  *&  *&  *&  *& \\ 
 1&  1&  n-1&  *&  *&  1& \\ 
 1&  n&  1&  &  *&  1& 
\end{vmatrix}$

Here, $D$ is defined by:

$$
D_{ij} = \begin{cases} i & \mathrm{if}\ i+j=n+2 \\ 1 & \mathrm{else}\end{cases}
$$

What I've done so far:

$D = \begin{vmatrix}
 1&  1& *&  *&  1&  1& \\ 
 1&  1&  *&  *&  1&  2& \\ 
 *&  *&  *&  1&  3&  1& \\ 
 *&  *&  *&  4&  1&  1& \\ 
 *&  *&  *&  *&  *&  *& \\ 
 1&  1&  n-1&  *&  *&  1& \\ 
 1&  n&  1&  *&  *&  1& 
\end{vmatrix}\xrightarrow[i \neq 1]{R_{i}\rightarrow R_{i} - R_{1}}
(-1)
\begin{vmatrix}
 1&  1& *&  *&  1&  1& \\ 
 0&  0&  *&  *&  0&  1& \\ 
 *&  *&  *&  0&  2&  0& \\ 
 *&  *&  *&  3&  0&  0& \\ 
 *&  *&  *&  *&  *&  *& \\ 
 0&  0&  n-2&  0&  *&  0& \\ 
 0&  n-1&  0&  *&  *&  0& 
\end{vmatrix}$

$det(A) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}(-1)^{i+1}a_{i1}+\det(A_{i1}^{M}) = (-1) * \begin{vmatrix}
 0&  0&  *&  *&  0& 1&  \\ 
 0&  0&  *&  *&  2&  0&\\ 
 *&  *&  *&  *&  *&  *&\\ 
 *&  *&  *&  *&  *&  *&\\ 
 0&  n-2&  0&  *&  0& 0&\\ 
 n-1&  0&  *&  *&  *&  0&
\end{vmatrix}$

How should I best proceed?

Comment: Are the stars in the very last matrix representing zeroes? Cofactor expansion should allow you to compute the last determinant then.

Comment: The stars are presumably all $1$'s, but the OP should realize his use of stars is highly confusing. He probably should learn how to use $\cdots$ and even $\ddots$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can compute the terms of the sum in the Leibniz formula:

$$\det(A) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \left( \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,\sigma_i}\right)$$

It is clear from visual inspection of your last $n \times n$ matrix that only one term in this sum is nonzero. This is because each row besides the first has only one nonzero term, and so only one permutation, $\sigma^*$, chooses a nonzero term in each row.

A simple induction on $n$ shows that the value of $\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma^*)$ is $(-1)^n$. This yields a final answer of $$(-1)^n(n-1)!$$

Comment: The $*$s, in my experience, tend to refer to unknown matrix entries, not necessarily zero entries. Given the OP uses both $*$ and $0$ in some parts of the matrix, I don't think assuming that $* = 0$ is a safe assumption.

Comment: @TheoBendit I did not assume them to be $0$, I assumed them to be $1$.